# I have a Problem with function OnClick Fragment _kotlin in Android studio

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, onclick, fragment

[Hello everybody,I Add OnClick in XML_Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R0BL.jpg)

[in code_fragment , function Don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKkfI.png)

[but in layout,function is work , ,How do you do for work with code fragment?,Thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odtC2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add onClick property for each element in your layout.
You can directly make the fragment extends the OnClickListener interface.

- extend your fragment with OnClickListener
- then implement onClickListener methods
- in the onClick method, do the stuff you want (nembrememore)